# Tennis Tournament Pairing (1x3x5x7x9x...(2n-1) )

Tags: algorithm

Need help with this algorithm problem: In a tennis tournament game we have 2n players. in the first round, each player only plays once, therefore we have n games, each game with 2 players. Show that the pairing of players for the first round can be done precisely with 1 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 9 ... (2n-1).

It looks as though it's factorial, but with odd numbers. All I read about factorials never come to this conclusion, and in a combination problem, sources only explain the possible pairings on a 1 on 1 ratio, not a 2 on 1, as it is in this case (2 players per game). Reading and reading has gotten me nowhere.

Comment: The function that you mention is called the double factorial and is sometimes abbreviated _n!!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer illustrates an inductive proof of the number of tournaments *t* over a set of *n* pairs of vertices. For a simpler, direct counting approach, see Daniel Fischer's answer.

I use [strong induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#complete_induction) to show *t*( *n* ) = (2 *n* - 1)!!.

For a basis, let *n* = 1. So we have *t*(1) = (2 - 1)!! = 1. Since there can be only 1 tournament with 1 pair of players, the basis checks.

Next, we assume that *t* = (2 *m* - 1)!! for all *m* < *n* and we let *i* + 1 = *n*. We start with a tournament of *i* pairs, add a new pair to make *n* pairs, and show that *t*( *n* ) = (2 n - 1)!!. There are two cases to consider. **Case 1:** the new pair plays against itself, and **case 2:**, it doesn't. Since the two cases are mutually exclusive, we can determine the number of tournaments generated by each case separately and add the results.

Considering case 1, how many ways can we match the new pair to the existing players? Well, the first player of the new pair can play any 2 *i* existing players and the second player can play any 2 *i* - 1 remaining players. Hence the total number of match-ups of the new pair is 2 *i* (2 *i* - 1). Of course after we match the new pair we cannot forget there are *i* - 1 pairs left. By the inductive hypothesis, we can match these players (2 (*i* - 1) - 1)!! ways. After applying the product rule for counting, the result for case 1 is 2 *i* (2 *i* - 1) (2 (*i* - 1) - 1)!!.

Turning to case 2, the new pair can play itself 1 way. By the inductive hypothesis the remaining *i* pairs can form a tournament (2 *i* - 1)!! ways, so the total for case 2 is (2 *i* - 1)!!.

Adding the two cases together we have *t*( *n* ) = 2 *i* (2 *i* - 1) (2 (*i* - 1) - 1)!! + (2 *i* - 1)!!.

We factor out a (2 (*i* - 1) - 1)!! on the right side to get *t*( *n* ) = (2 (*i* - 1) - 1)!! (2 *i* (2 *i* - 1) + (2 *i* - 1)).

Combining like terms we have *t*( *n* ) = (2 (*i* - 1) - 1)!! (2 *i* - 1)(2 *i* + 1).

Folding the trailing factors into the double factorial we have *t*( *n* ) = (2 (*i* + 1) - 1)!!

Finally, we apply the definition of *i* and we have  *t*( *n* ) = (2 n - 1)!!

Answer (score 1):

Obvoiusly, for `n = 1`, there is exactly one way to pair the two players.

Now, inductively, player 1 can be paired with `2*n - 1` players, and the remaining `2*(n-1)` players can then be paired in

```
1*3*...*(2*n-3)
```

ways by the induction hypothesis, for a total of `1*3*...*(2*n-3)*(2*n-1)` ways.

Comment: um, this is not mathematical induction. You are simply applying the product rule for combinatorics. However, induction is not necessary for this problem. The product rule is sufficient.

Comment: Umm, I'm proving that the formula holds for all `n >= 1` using induction (_and_ the product rule). That's not the only way, of course, but the easiest.

Comment: Given some _n_, one can solve this problem directly for that _n_, hence no induction is necessary. We must use induction when a solution for _n_ is not apparent. In such a case, one proposes a solution and proves 1) it's true for the base case and 2) that _if_ it's true for _n_, _then_ it's true for _n_ + 1. Notice that with induction, one never proves the solution for _n_ directly.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Sure, one can prove it without induction, but why bother if the inductive proof is immediately obvious?

Comment: Because what you have here is not an inductive proof at all, it's a deductive, aka direct proof.

Comment: Induction start: The formula holds for the base case. Induction step: assuming the formula holds for `n`, prove that it holds for `n+1`. I haven't spelled it out in all details, but it is induction.

Comment: No, you deduced the number of choices for the nth player, then based on number of player left, you deduced the number of choices for the (n-3)th player, and so on to the (n-(n-2))th player, who only has one choice. Then you took all those choices and multiplied them, following the product rule. That's pure deduction. There was no induction involved.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. All mathematical proofs are pure deduction. Mathematical induction is a form of deduction, too. So induction vs. deduction is a false dichotomy. And I formulated the proof as an induction, though abbreviated, because that's the easiest way to formulate it, given my background.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is incorrect. But to call it induction, you would need to show that tourn_count(_n_) == (2 _n_ - 1)!! implies tourn_count(_n_ +1 ) == (2 _n_ + 1)!!. You're not doing that.

Comment: I do. I say `tourn_count(n-1) == (2n-3)!!` **by the induction hypothesis**. And that is used to determine `tourn_count(n) == (2*n-1)!!`. So 1. P(1); 2. For `n > 1`, P(n-1) + trivially_true_stuff => P(n).

Comment: Your comment states the correct form of induction but your answer directly counts the tournaments for n pairs. You start with 'player 1' and multiply the ways for each player. That's direct counting. Induction requires, after you prove the basis, that you _start with_ an assumption for n-1 pairs. See my answer for correct inductive method

Comment: No. I don't need to _start_ with the result for `n-1` pairs for it to be induction, I just need to _use_ that result to prove the result for `n` pairs. Although, formally, I can write up an inductive proof even without using P(n) in proving P(n+1). That would be a non-inductive proof dressed up as an inductive proof, but formally an inductive proof (proving `{} => A` is also a proof of `{B} => A`). You could argue that I only use the induction hypothesis to shortcut "then the player with the next lowest number not yet matched can be paired with `2*n-3` other players, and then ...", yes, but?